# how to create table definition from csv file and also copy data at the same time

Tags: vertica

I want to load data from a `csv` file into Vertica. I don't want to `create table` and the `copy` data in two separate steps. Instead, I want to create the table, specify the `csv` file and then let `vertica` figure out column definitions (names, data type) itself and then load the data.

Something like `create table titanic_train () as COPY FROM '/data/train.csv' PARSER fcsvparser() rejected data as table titanic_train_rejected abort on error no commit;`

Is it possible?

I guess that if a table has 100s of columns then automating the create table, column definition and data copy would be much easier/faster than doing these steps separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always several steps, no matter what.

1. Use the built-in bits of Vertica:

```
CREATE FLEX TABLE foo();
COPY foo FROM '/data/mycsvs/foo.csv' PARSER fCsvParser();
SELECT COMPUTE_FLEXTABLE_KEYS_AND_BUILD_VIEW('foo');
-- THEN, either:
SELECT * FROM foo_view;
-- OR: create a ROS Table:
CREATE TABLE foo_ros AS SELECT * FROM foo_view;
```

2. Get a CSV-to-DDL parser from the net, like https://github.com/marco-the-sane/d2l, and install it then:

```sh
$ d2l -coldelcomma -chardelquote -drp -copy /data/mycsvs/foo.csv | vsql
```

So , in the second instance, it's one step, but it calls both `d2l` and `vsql`.

Comment: If I have 3 node cluster, then does the `.csv` file need to be on all nodes? At the moment, I am running things on laptop using Vertica's docker image (so 1 node). Wondering if the flex table approach would work on multi-node cluster. Would it? How?

Comment: with d2l, it would be just the node on which you run d2l. With the flex table and copy: either you copy the file to all nodes and go `... FROM '/data/mycsvs/foo.csv' ON ANY NODE PARSER fCsvParser()`, or you put it just on node 1, and go `... FROM '/data/mycsvs/foo.csv' ON v_«db name»_node0001 PARSER fCsvParser()`

Comment: What is the difference between `SELECT * FROM foo_view` and `CREATE TABLE foo_ros AS SELECT * FROM foo_view`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM foo_view` will return all work from the table to the calling client. `CREATE TABLE foo_ros AS SELECT * FROM foo_view` won't return any rows and create a new physical ROS table containing the result table of the full-select.